# How to fix error with SFML ln VS 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

Hi i followed this video to set-up VS2017 for sfml using.
[Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axIgxBQVBg0)

I did what he says but when i debug project i get this error:

```
Error   MSB6006 "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741515.
```

I find out on google that this is some sort of compiler error but not how to fix this. Can someone help me or point me to answer? 
I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and i downloaded SFML: Visual C++ 14 (2015) - 32-bit

Comment: Is that the full error? Check the "Output" tab if you haven't already.

Comment: @Quentin Yes it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, you compiler crashed. The status code `-1073741515` translates to `0xC0000135` which in turn translates to `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND`. That is bad. That is not about the SFML dlls, but a library Visual Studio *itself* uses. Something is very wrong with your Visual Studio installation.

Chances are you will get the same error without using SFML.

I don't know what the tutorial did and I'm not going to watch a video to find out. Your best chance is to do a clean reinstall of your Visual Studio installation and then follow the [official guide from the SFML homepage](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/start-vc.php). That works.